# Wxpython's gauge not refreshing

Tags: python, wxpython

I'd like to make an upload program with uploading gauge. I've got function which is callback function:

```
def myupdater(self, current, total):

    m = (Decimal(current)/Decimal(total))
    print "uploaded {0}/{1} so far".format(current, total)
    self.gauge_1.SetValue(m)
    print(m)
    print (self.gauge_1.GetValue)
    wx.Yield()
    print"----------------------"
```

And it shows (gauge only changes to 100% at the end):

http://pastebin.com/eM40e6mv

Full code:
http://pastebin.com/uaThd5sD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Gauge`'s range is int type.](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxgauge.html#wxgaugector) Passing value lower than 1 is treated as 0. Change `gauge_1 ..` line as follow:

```
self.gauge_1 = wx.Gauge(self.notebook_1_pane_1, -1, 100)
```

Change `myupdater` as follow:

```
def myupdater(self, current, total):
    m = 100 * current / total
    self.gauge_1.SetValue(m)
    wx.Yield()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a worker thread to update your GUI while the file is uploading. Try the threading module:

```
import threading

def myupdater(self):
    while self.still_uploading:
        #do stuff

threading.Thread(target=myupdater).start()
#upload stuff here
```

Comment: I see an unused import of the Thread class. It seems that your current code only calls the myupdater function when it's done uploading, you'll need to use the threading module.